# PostThreadMessage C++ (CWinThread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

i'm using MFC C++ and I'm trying to send message to CWinThread using PostThreadMessage from Dlg Class and the message isn't handled on the thread class

.H file of the thread:

```
   #define Message_Test_Id WM_USER + 1

   class CTestMsg : public CWinThread
   {
       DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CTestMsg)

       protected:
       CTestMsg();           // protected constructor used by dynamic        creation
       virtual ~CTestMsg();

   public:
       virtual BOOL InitInstance();
       virtual int ExitInstance();

   protected:
       afx_msg void OnTestMsg(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);//The Message
       DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

};

.cpp of the thread:

```
   BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestMsg, CWinThread)
       ON_THREAD_MESSAGE(Message_Test_Id,OnTestMsg)
   END_MESSAGE_MAP()

   ....
   void CTestMsg::OnTestMsg(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
     ...
   }
```

And I'm trying to send the message in the Dlg class:

```
   CTestMsg *m_testMsg = (CTestMsg*)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CTestMsg),THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 10000, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);

       m_testMsg->PostThreadMessageW(Message_Test_Id, 0, 0);
```

why the message isn't handled? thanks! (sorry on my bad Engllish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your thread with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, to make it actually run you must resume it with:

```
m_testMsg->ResumeThread();
```

Comment: btw, when the thread is 'dead'? if I call to ResumeThread then Run() method is calling and then the thread is 'dead'? what is the life cycle of CWinThread?

Comment: Thread will end when its message loop will break, you can do this by calling `PostQuitMessage(0);`

Comment: Ok, and what is the best why to kill the thread while the application is running? it's right to do m_testMsg->Delete(); if not, what is the best way to kill the thread?beacuse PostQuitMessage(0) kill also that my application :D

Comment: Its best not to kill threads, as it might cause undefined behaviour in your application. As I said, to stop your UI thread call `m_testMsg->PostQuitMessage(0);`, but this must be done from your m_testMsg thread, so if you want to stop it from some other thread then use m_testMsg->PostThreadMessage to post message which once received will call PostQuitMessage(0);.

Comment: Oh Thanks again!,so i'm need to send to the thread message with id example "Message_quit" and then the thread on the message callback need to call PostQuitMessage? and this is the best way to kill the thread?

Comment: It should suffice to call `::PostQuitMessage(0);`, but it must be done from inside of your m_testMsg thread. I suppose you could simply do `m_testMsg->PostThreadMessage(WM_QUIT,0,0);`

Comment: Ok, and this is the best way to kill the thread? and again, Thank you very very much!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ShaySmadja for a simple scenerio - yes.

Comment: @marcinj: Unless you provide a concise specification for *simple scenario*, you can't call your proposition *safe*. [Why is there a special PostQuitMessage function?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx) explains what you're missing out on, when calling `PostThreadMessage`. Also note that messages posted to a thread can get lost ([Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx)).